# Length of string from array Perl always returns 1

Tags: arrays, regex, string, perl

I am trying to get length of element of array( string) ,but I am getting 1 each time.
Here is my code

```
while (my $line =<$file>) {
  chomp $line;
my @words = split('', $line);
foreach my $element (@words)
{
  print length($element);
}
```

Length always returns 1, but with other variable it works fine.
Please help to find problem.

Comment: It will. You're printing the length inside the foreach loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used

```
split('', $line)
```

That tells Perl to split `$line` into individual characters. I think you meant to use

```
split(' ', $line)
```

This tells Perl to split `$line` into "words" (sequences of characters separated by whitespace).

Answer (score 1):

Use a regexpr in [split function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

```
my @words = split(/\s+/, $line);
```

`\s` means the [whitespace](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Whitespace) and `+` one or more ocurrences

Comment: I believe the special case `split ' '` is better than `split /\s+/` for the task at hand. They are identical except the former ignores any leading whitespace that would cause the latter to return an empty leading field.